# wp.template() returns <script> tags in Ajax response

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, javascript, backbone

I'm using the `wp.template()` to create a BackBone JS template which comes with WordPress by default.

I have a template defined as:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-pre-registration">
    <div className="stvp-preregistration">
        <form className="stvp-preregistration__form" id="stvp-preregistration__form">
            <label htmlFor="stvp-preregistration__email-input">{{ data.name }}</label>
            <input placeholder='Email' type="email" name="stvp-preregistration-email-input" id="stvp-preregistration-email-input"/>
            <input id="stvp-preregistration__email-submit" type="submit" disabled />
        </form>
        <p className="stvp-preregistration__message">Some Message</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

I am trying to set certain values in the template which I receive from Ajax response.

But my Ajax response includes the above script with it.

[image]

As you see, I just want the response to be:
`{"success":false,"exit":false}`

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: how did you included this?

Comment: I solved this, I included it using require_once, now I've included it using the `wp_footer` hook